# How do I toggle the graphical desktop (GDM)?

Tags: gdm

I am using Ubuntu 10.10 desktop, but i need to shut off graphic window (gdm) and and make it alive when a need it, how can i do that?

Thanks in advance

Rick

Answer (score 1):

To stop GDM:

```
sudo stop gdm
```

Make sure you're logged out from the graphical login or you might loose data.

To start it again, use:

```
sudo start gdm
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only need a terminal, and not to close everything in the GUI, press Ctrl+Alt+ one of the F1 to F6 Keys. You will get a fullscreen login terminal. To switch back, press Ctrl+Alt+F7.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want GDM to start automatically just edit "/etc/default/grub" and modify the line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

in

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash text"
```

then type:

```
sudo update-grub
```

then, you can start GDM at any time by typing:

```
sudo service gdm start
```

or just run the default DE by typing:

```
startx
```